# Making an array of textboxes is not working

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

Ok so here is my designer.cs code

```
for (int i = 0; i < textBoxes.Length; i++)
{
    textBoxes[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
    this.textBoxes[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(90, 50 + i * 20);
    this.textBoxes[i].Name = "textBox" + i;
    this.textBoxes[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
    this.textBoxes[i].TabIndex = i + 1;

    this.Controls.Add(textBoxes[i]);
}
```

This was edited code below the Windows Generated code

```
private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox[] textBoxes = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox[5];
```

I deleted any code that is related to any of my textboxes.

Instead it's giving me this error when I go to the design view:

```
Games MoreGames.Designer.cs Line:32 Column:1
```

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fl9n4.png)

The program can run but why wouldn't it let me access the designer so I can move things around?

Comment: Is that the whole error?

Comment: @David It's the MoreGames.cs [design] that's blocking me from editing it. Yeah it seems like this is the whole error.

Comment: Define "blocking me from editing it."  Are you getting a compiler error?  Some sort of Visual Studio error when you try to open the file?  The problem description is pretty vague so far.

Comment: @David Should I give a screenshot? I'll upload it now.

Comment: I suggest you look in the Output window - there's likely to be more information there.

Comment: Did you actually read the error message? You should not be manually editing the generated code. Let the designer take care of the designer generated code.

Comment: @PhoenixReborn But how do I make a array of textboxes then?

Comment: Ya, that *entire paragraph* of an error message in the screen shot is much more meaningful than just a reference to a line of code.  What you're trying to do is a bit broken.  In general you usually don't want to edit the designer file manually, not unless you *really* know what you're doing.  You can create an array of text boxes in the normal code file and apply it to the form when it loads.  Though I wonder if an array of text boxes is even the right approach for whatever you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joel says, you should place that code in the constructor following the `InitializeComponent()` method in your MoreGames.cs file (NOT MoreGames.Designer.cs which cannot be edited) but you might also want to add the following:

```
textboxes[i].Parent = this;
```

That will tell each of your textboxes that the form is it's parent.

The basic namespace of your Form will look something like this:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox[] textBoxes = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox[5];

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int i = 0; i < textBoxes.Length; i++)
            {
                textBoxes[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
                this.textBoxes[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(90, 50 + i * 20);
                this.textBoxes[i].Name = "textBox" + i;
                this.textBoxes[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
                this.textBoxes[i].TabIndex = i + 1;
                this.textBoxes[i].Parent = this;
                this.Controls.Add(textBoxes[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So I put this code in the InitializeComponent() right? The code you gave me not Joel

Comment: Copy your entire for loop into the Form Constructor *after* the *InitializeComponent()* call.  Place the line of code I gave you before the `this.controls.add(...` line in your for loop.

Comment: Thanks for this. Also, I guess there is no way I can display those text boxes when I use the design view right? But if I run it then it would display properly.

Comment: That's correct.  You cannot display dynamically added controls in the designer, only at runtime.  This may be a little counter-intuitive if you're used to the VB6 forms designer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot edit the designer.cs file. Or rather, you can edit the file, but any changes you make will be **overwritten** every time the designer needs to regenerate the file, and certain things in the file will prevent the visual designer from rendering your form properly. This is by design.

What you should do instead is put your code in your form's constructor, immediately following the call to the `InitializeComponent()` method. The new controls won't show up on the screen for you to drag around, but they will be there when you actually run the program.

Moreover, it sounds like what you really need here is something that is more data driven, like a FlowLayoutPanel, that you can add and remove controls from at run time.

Comment: It works and I can edit the design CS file but the problem is that I can't see the text boxes unless I run it.