# Why isn't my label displaying the number?

Tags: c#, winforms, label

So I know my calculations may be large. However, when I try to do calculate the input cubed of the textbox adjacent to it, it won't display the number but it will display the string "exp: ".

Is this concatenation not working? Instead, it's only displaying "EXP: " if it's too large.

Also, I tried it the other way around but it will display the number (even if it's large) but not " exp".

```
for (int i = 0; i < textBoxes.Length; i++)
{
    totalExp += Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(textBoxes[i].Text), 3.0) + 1;
    labels[i].Text = "Exp: " + (Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(textBoxes[i].Text), 3.0) + 1).ToString("#,###.#####");
}
```

The textbox properties were set on my last question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20406828/2804613)

I did the exact same thing with the labels so that they are on the right side of the textbox.

Comment: Is it a web application? If so, have you check the HTML source for the page? The number might be there but not displaying in the browser.

Comment: @acfrancis It's a Windows Form Application.

Comment: My guess is that the number is coming back as positive infinity, therefore cannot be formatted as a number.

Comment: @paqogomez I was able to calculate the exp without the concatenation. I've gone as high as a few thousand for input.

Comment: why you repeat your calculation? save `Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(textBoxes[i].Text), 3.0) + 1` to a variable and use this variable to add to `totalExp` and formatting a string. If the calculation/operation take long time, your application run two times longer.

Comment: @Carnifex Total EXP is for the sum of multiple textboxes. It's separate calculation btw. That's why I can't use a variable. My label text is supposed to be used for individual text boxes for displaying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explaining my comment:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < textBoxes.Length; i++)
{
    var exp = Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(textBoxes[i].Text), 3.0) + 1;
    totalExp += exp;
    labels[i].Text = "Exp: " + exp.ToString("#,###.#####");
}
```

Better way to do this is using String.Format()

```
for (int i = 0; i < textBoxes.Length; i++)
{
    var exp = Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(textBoxes[i].Text), 3.0) + 1;
    totalExp += exp;
    labels[i].Text = String.Format("Exp: {0:#,###.#####}", exp);
}
```

And make sure you set `AutoSize` property of the label to `True`.

Comment: It actually worked without the string format way. All I did was just set every label to true AutoSize. I guess it saves typing then with your String.Format() code or is it faster to run?

Comment: It's faster, because we do not reserve memory for all different values of string. Each concatenation of string require separate memory - this is why for lots of concatenation we prefer StringBuilder. In this case is similar. Although String.Format is a little slower then pure .ToString() is a far more readable and clean.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to reproduce your problem using the following code:

```
    double thisExp = Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble("1.37"), 3.0) + 1;
    // totalExp += thisExp;
    string Text = "Exp: " + thisExp.ToString("#,###.#####");

    Console.WriteLine(Text);
```

It prints

> Exp: 3.57135

You can try it out [here](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_csharp_online.php)

It is therefore not a formatting problem. I suspect the conversion from string to double, but we need more information for that. **Especially** locale settings and the exact string contents.

A second thought: Can you read back the label text? If you set the label size too narrow for the text, it may just display the first few characters.

Comment: Hmm, I tried using console and it worked fine. I even entered a really large input (34999) and it gave me the result I was looking for. The label text is inside a group box but I'll try to make the group box a lot wider. EDIT: Wider group box and screen doesn't seem to help :(

Comment: And on what input do you observe the problem? I can produce a result of "Exp: " by entering "-1". But it would really help if you'd provide something like "exact input", "expected output" and "actual output".

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/1hE5IVa.png In this Screenshot, I'm trying to input in the textboxes (I found a way that you don't have to enter all 10 boxes and the program will stay safe). Basically, a label will display on the right side of the textbox based in input cubed. Then the total level is cuberoot(sum of inputcubed). Total in x don't worry about it.